# TinyMCE - How to remove IDs from pasted HTML?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

If someone pastes content from an HTML page, the IDs of that page's elements are pasted with it. This messes up a lot if it later causes duplicate IDs when the content is displayed.

**How can I strip all the IDs (and classes for that matter) from any pasted content but still retain the tags?**

Here's an excerpt of my instantiation:

```
        menubar : false,
        statusbar : false,
        content_css : "css/mce.css",
        contextmenu : "link image jbimage paste inserttable | cell row column deletetable",
        plugins : [
            "advlist autolink lists link image charmap anchor",
            "code fullscreen media table contextmenu paste jbimages paste"
        ],
        paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste : true,
        paste_strip_class_attributes:"all",
        menubar : false,
        toolbar : "fontselect |  fontsizeselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | link image jbimages media | fullscreen | setSection code",
        toolbar_items_size : 'small',
        force_br_newlines : true,
        force_p_newlines : false,
        forced_root_block : '',
        title : "",
        mode : "textareas",
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [paste_preprocess](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3apaste_preprocess) setting of tinymce and define something like the following

```
ed.settings.paste_preprocess = function(pl, o)
{
    o.content = o.content.replace(/ id="(.*?)"/ig, "");
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't that replace any instance of id="<anything>" ? As this project is for learning materials of all kinds, I can definitely see that running into issues. For example: an HTML or programming tutorial or paper where a code snippet or pre tags could contain id="..."